# Check the occurrence of zero or one substring

Tags: python, regex

Could anyone please point me how to check a pattern in which a sub-pattern occurs zero or once?

For example,

```
Test 1-2 (many): blah blah
Test 1-2: blah blah
```

Both lines should be detected.

I tried with:

```
sub = 'Test\s+(\d+\s*\-\s*\d+)\s*\((.*?)\)?(\:*)\s*(.*)'
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What doesn't work as expected? Could you show us your code?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Checking whether a sub-pattern occurs zero times is true of every string. Can you clarify your intent with additional input/output examples with a clear explanation of what characteristics about the input are relevant?

Comment: with my sub, I can't detect the case (Test 1-2: blah blah). that is what I mean "doesn't work as expected". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to match a sub-pattern which occurs zero or once:

```
(?:sub_pattern)?
```

where **`(?:...)`** is a non-capturing group. In your particular example, the question mark(to match zero or one sub-pattern) is set to `\)?`, this influences only the single preceding closing parenthesis ')'. you should put the whole optional sub-pattern into a non-capturing group, thus:

```
(?:\(.*?\))?
```

**Note:** Do NOT use the capturing groups **`(...)`** unless you want to extract their values separately.

Below is a testing code for a full regex pattern:

```
import re

# a list of testing strings
x = ['Test 1-2 (many): blah blah', 'Test 1-2: blah blah', 'Test 1: no match']

# regex pattern
sub = r'Test\s+\d+\s*-\s*\d+\s*(?:\(.*?\))?:.+'  

for i in x:
    m = re.match(sub, i)
    if m: print(m.group(0)) 
#Test 1-2 (many): blah blah
#Test 1-2: blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can add an optional sub-expression, behind the `:`, collect our value after that in a capturing group and collect our numbers and dashes in another one, maybe similar to:

```
Test\s+([0-9-]+)(.+)?:\s+(.+)
```

If we wish to add more boundaries, we can do that. The rest of our work can be programmed.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Tww6TX/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"Test\s+([0-9-]+)(.+?):\s+(.+)"

test_str = ("Test 1-2 (many): blah blah\n"
    "Test 1-2: blah blah")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /Test\s+([0-9-]+)(.+)?:\s+(.+)/gm;
const str = `Test 1-2 (many): blah blah
Test 1-2: blah blah`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Another Approach by [Kenan Güler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6576367/kenan-g%C3%BCler)

RegExp: `^(Test\s+\d+-\d+)\b(?:.*?:\s*)(.*)$`

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/LovableCaringBrowser

```py
  import re

  base_sub_pattern = ["Test 1-2", "blah blah"]

  string = """\
  Test 1-2 (many): blah blah
  Test 1-2: blah blahGGG
  """

  pattern = re.compile(r"^(Test\s+\d+-\d+)\b(?:.*:\s*)(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
  matches = pattern.findall(string)

  if matches:
    print("found matches:", matches, "\n")

    for match in matches:
      if set(base_sub_pattern).difference(match):
        print("sub-pattern not exist here", match)
```